# Adding a UINavigationController built with IB

Tags: xcode, ios, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

Building an iPhone application.  The delegate loads a SplashScreenView which sits there until the user taps the screen.  When the user is done tapping the screen, I release that view and I want to load my custom Navigation Controller.  I can't figure out how to load the Navigation Controller I designed in IB...it's currently loading a blank instance of UINavigationController.

I'm running this from my delegate:

```
mnc = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNavigation" bundle:nil];
[self.window addSubview:mnc.view];
```

MyNavigation is a XIB I created which only has File's Owner/First Responder/a Navigation Controller I added.  I set the class of File's Owner to MyNavigationController but I'm not sure how to tell it that I want the view "MyNavigationController" uses to be the one I designed.  When I try to drag the "view" outlet of File's Owner in IB to my designed Navigation Controller, it doesn't seem to like it.

I'm just not sure how to connect the dots here.  Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the root controller of your navigation controller? The "blank" thing that you see is probably your navigation controller loaded with no controllers for it to navigate.

**Update**

You don't need "two controllers" per se. It's just that navigation controller is the one that controls the stack of other controllers you provide it with. First you init your navigation controller with root view controller (with `initWithRootViewController` method you mentioned), then you can push (`pushViewController:animated:`) or pop (`popViewController:animated:`) other controllers to or off of the stack of navigation controller.

Apple developer documentation provides plenty information in view controller programming guide on how different types of view controllers interact.

Comment: I'm sure that's what I'm seeing.  I know I have a fundamental misunderstanding here.  Why do I need two controllers?  What is the purpose of the root view controller?  I see the method of initWithRootViewController but I'd be purely guessing as to what to instantiate that with.

Comment: I understand the concept of pushing views onto the navigation controller and I can get that to work when I do a Navigation based application and the Navigation Controller is in the MainWindow.xib, but I'm trying to get a deeper understanding here.  When I go to init my Navigation Controller, I do this:

gnc = [[GeoNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:???

I have absolutely no idea what it's looking for there.  I don't have any other view controller objects at this point.

Comment: It doesn't matter WHERE is your navigation controller as long as you can reach it. Only thing that matters is the controller you initialize it with. Might there be a chance that you want generic navigation controller with `GeoNavigationController` as your root view controller from which you will navigate to detail view controllers?

Comment: Why can't I just create an instance of my GeoNavigationController and add it to window and then push views to the controller later?  I think my confusion really lies in doing this with Interface Builder.  I added a toolbar and buttons and made the "shell" look the way I want it to.  When I do this: gnc = [[GeoNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeoNavigation" bundle:nil]; and then [self.window addSubview:gnc.view], I don't see my customized layout.  I see a blank navigation controller.

Comment: If you want your GeoNavigationController to be displayed - then it's not navigation controller. It's simple view controller that should be put into navigation controller from where you will be able to push other controllers on top of geo view controller __inside__ simple navigation controller.

Comment: I think I completely understand that.  I add my navigation controller and then I can add views to them using the push/popViewController methods.  The only disconnect I have right now is, when I instantiate my GeoNavigationController, how do I associate that with the design I built in Interface Builder?  I know I'm doing an awful job of communicating this and I really appreciate your help.  I just don't understand why my toolbar/buttons aren't displaying.  All I need is to tie my instance of GeoNavigationController to the layout I built in Interface Builder.

Comment: Check if outlets from file owner (defined as GeoNavigationController instance) to the view object (which is in the same xib file) are established.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  The view outlet is not connected to anything.  There's no view inside of my XIB at all, just a UINavigationController.  I set File's Owner AND the UINavigationController I designed to both have the class GeoNavigationController.  If I try to set the view outlet by dragging it over the Nav Controller I designed, the only things I can connect it to are the toolbar and the navigation bar.  I can't connect to the "view" as a whole.  This would be a lot easier to visually demonstrate, unfortunately.

Comment: I give up.  I'm accepting your answer because you've been so helpful. I ended up just creating a UINavigationController programmatically and then setting the rootViewController property of my window to that object.  I'll just try to find a way to add the buttons manually.  Thank you for your help!